# Select beginning of latest consecutive groups for all values in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have the following table:

| weekStart | bcid |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-07-18 | df9bd190-417d-4007-9dc7-1de0a5ba4045 |
| 2022-07-25 | e46ac8ed-bcc5-4dab-9694-479637e1ee99 |
| 2022-08-01 | e46ac8ed-bcc5-4dab-9694-479637e1ee99 |
| 2022-08-01 | df9bd190-417d-4007-9dc7-1de0a5ba4045 |
| 2022-08-08 | df9bd190-417d-4007-9dc7-1de0a5ba4045 |
| 2022-08-08 | ca3fd5c6-73d0-4104-aa03-dcc0eb263c0a |
| 2022-08-08 | e46ac8ed-bcc5-4dab-9694-479637e1ee99 |

I need to find for every `bcid` the latest `weekStart` after which it appeared every "week" (i.e. group). That is, each value may appear consistently every week, then disappear and, at some point, come back. And I need the start date of this last (newest) group in which value started to appear consecutively again.

E.g. for `df9bd190-417d-4007-9dc7-1de0a5ba4045` this should be 2022-08-01 and not 2022-07-18, because it was missing in 2022-07-25.

I currently think towards windowed functions, but not sure how to get to the "consecutively" part:

```sql
select bcid, min(min("weekStart")) over (partition by bcid) as "firstAppearedLatest"
from tx
group by bcid
```

Can assume that there are no weeks skipped between first and last `weekStart` values.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/72bb28)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, mark all the groups using `lag()` to check to see if there is a break.

Next, give group numbers to the groupings (casting `boolean` to `int` gives `1` for `true` and `0` for `false`).

Use `distinct on` to grab the record to keep:

```
with mark_gaps as (
  select *,
         "weekStart" > lag("weekStart") over w + interval '7 days' as new_group
    from tx
  window w as (partition by bcid order by "weekStart")
), group_nums as (
  select *, 
         sum(coalesce(new_group, true)::int) over w as group_num
    from mark_gaps
  window w as (partition by bcid order by "weekStart")
)
select distinct on (bcid) bcid, "weekStart"
  from group_nums
 order by bcid, group_num desc, "weekStart";
```

[Updated fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/72bb28/19)